# rec2csv exporting with a blank line between rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, recarray

I'm trying to export a a recarray to csv file with rec2csv so I can retrieve it later with csv2rec. The problem is that the rec2csv is exporting with a blank line between each rows, so csv2rec cannot read it later. How can I fix this problem with the function rec2csv?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
ticker = 'GOOG'
startdate = datetime.date(2011,1,1)
enddate = datetime.date.today()
fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate)
r = mlab.csv2rec(fh); fh.close()
r.sort()
```

After some calculations,

```
fl = open(r'J:\export.csv', 'w')
mlab.rec2csv(r,fl); fl.close()
```

Then I want to be able to import this file again with:

```
ff = mlab.csv2rec('J:\\export.csv')
```

This give an error message (IndexError: list index out of range) because there are blank lines between rows.

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that... What does your data look like? Do you have a string array (or field) that has newlines in it?  By the way, the functions you're referring to aren't numpy functions. They're matplotlib functions.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch stock data from yahoo finance using csv2rec and save it as csv file with rec2csv. When I do it, the file looks like this:
\n
date,open,high,low,close,volume,adj_close
\n
2011-01-03,49.399999999999999,50.090000000000003,49.100000000000001,49.899999999999999,12745700,49.43
\n
2011-01-04,50.140000000000001,50.829999999999998,50.100000000000001,50.829999999999998,20270600,50.350000000000001
\n
2011-01-05,50.369999999999997,51.649999999999999,50.369999999999997,51.560000000000002,17732400,51.07
\n

I don't know how to eliminate this empty line between each data.

Comment: Can you show us a reproducible example? (Or a bit more of what you're doing, at least?)

Comment: Things work perfectly here... It could be a line ending problem. Windows does things I don't understand when opening files it thinks are text. What happens if you either a) Open the file using the `'wb'` mode, or b) just pass in the file name instead of manually opening the file. (The result should be the same).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because you're not opening the file in binary mode.  `rec2csv` uses the builtin `csv` module, which expects the file to be opened in `'wb'` mode on Windows.

An easy solution is to just pass in the filename, instead of opening and closing the file manually.

So either do:

```
mlab.rec2csv(r, 'J:\\export.csv')
```

or do:

```
with open('J:\\export.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    mlab.rec2csv(r, outfile)
```

Comment: I got a message error:
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 2656, in rec2csv
    writer.writerow(header)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.

Is this related to python version, because I am using Python 3 and matplotlib for this version.